# Having problems installing Glassfish Tools (1.0.1) through Eclipse (2019-12)

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

I'm having troubles getting glassfish tools to install on my machine with fresh installs of the Eclipse IDE (2019-12), jdk 1.8.0_241, glassfish (5.1 Full Profile), and glassfish tools (1.0.1).

---

To recreate my problem, here's what I did:

1. Install Eclipse with the "Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers" flavor selected into a folder.
2. In that same folder, download and then extract the glassfish zip to that same folder.
3. Open eclipse and use the help menu to install software.
4. Putting the repository link for glassfish tools (https://download.eclipse.org/glassfish-tools/1.0.1/repository/) into the work with and installing both.

The error I get is:

```
  Software being installed: GlassFish Tools 1.0.1.201904090220 (org.eclipse.glassfish.tools.feature.group 1.0.1.201904090220)
  Missing requirement: GlassFish Tools 1.0.1.201904090220 (org.eclipse.glassfish.tools.feature.group 1.0.1.201904090220) requires 'org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.sapphire.feature.group [9.1.0,10.0.0)' but it could not be found.
```

---

I honestly can't think of the first step to try and fix this error, as all the googling about equinox.p2 and sapphire makes it out to be that they should be installed by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add https://download.eclipse.org/sapphire/9.1.1/repository/ to your list of Available Update Sites and try it again. The downloadable repository contains only the artifacts built from the Glassfish Tools project.